# How can i concatenate 2 strings in node.js?

Tags: javascript

```
var link = 'https://thisIsAlink'
var line = 'this is a line'
```

what i have done is

```
var full_path = session.send(link + line)
```

The output i got :`https://thisIsAlink this is a line`
The output i want :`https://thisIsAlinkthis is a line`

Comment: Having reread the question I realise that I got your desired and actual output backwards. There is no way that the code you provided will give the result you describe. The space can't appear from nowhere.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sigocezesu/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

```
Var1 = 'this sentence'
Var2 = 'new sentence'
Var2 += Var1
```

This output is : `new sentencethis sentence`
If you want just switch the contat and you get the opposite

Comment: Have you tried this?

var link = 'https://thisIsAlink'
var line = 'this is a line'
var link += line

var full_path = session.send(link)